# How to interact with second tab via javascript

Tags: javascript

So currently Im trying to make Google Chrome extension using Visual Studio Code and JavaScript. I havent worked with JS before. So I have this part right now, Im taking some info from the first page and then I open the second one and try to click button on it, but its still working only on the first one. Ive tried .focus and setTimeout but nothing works.

```
window.open("https://somesite");
setTimeout(1000)
document.querySelector(".submitButton").click()
```

Comment: if you open a new webpage, it's equivalent to running JS in the other page, writing code on the "first" page would not impact on other tab, you should move the logic to the 2nd page.

Comment: Are your pages two different pages?

Comment: So how can I move the logic to the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript only works on page when you code it.
If you want to create javascript on new page - you need to write all code again.

**On PAGE 2 button will not works , becuse JS is not shared on all pages. You needs to write again JS function to click that button**

Comment: can you drop an example please, still hard to understand?

Comment: dropped example .